# Solidity - Signing minting while testing a contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, signature

I am trying to create a test around a contract, but I am having problems understanding how to sign it in a test environment

This is my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.8.9 <0.9.0;

import "@divergencetech/ethier/contracts/crypto/SignatureChecker.sol";
import "@divergencetech/ethier/contracts/crypto/SignerManager.sol";
import "@divergencetech/ethier/contracts/erc721/BaseTokenURI.sol";
import "@divergencetech/ethier/contracts/erc721/ERC721ACommon.sol";
import "@divergencetech/ethier/contracts/erc721/ERC721Redeemer.sol";
import "@divergencetech/ethier/contracts/sales/FixedPriceSeller.sol";
import "@divergencetech/ethier/contracts/utils/Monotonic.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControlEnumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol";

interface ITokenURIGenerator {
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (string memory);
}

// @author divergence.xyz
contract TestBirds is
    ERC721ACommon,
    BaseTokenURI,
    FixedPriceSeller,
    ERC2981,
    AccessControlEnumerable
{
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;   
    using ERC721Redeemer for ERC721Redeemer.Claims;
    using Monotonic for Monotonic.Increaser;

    /**
    @notice Role of administrative users allowed to expel a Player from the
    mission.
    @dev See expelFromMission().
     */
    bytes32 public constant EXPULSION_ROLE = keccak256("EXPULSION_ROLE");

    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        string memory baseTokenURI,
        address payable beneficiary,
        address payable royaltyReceiver
    )
        ERC721ACommon(name, symbol)
        BaseTokenURI(baseTokenURI)
        FixedPriceSeller(
            2.5 ether,
            Seller.SellerConfig({
                totalInventory: 10_000,
                lockTotalInventory: true,
                maxPerAddress: 0,
                maxPerTx: 0,
                freeQuota: 125,
                lockFreeQuota: false,
                reserveFreeQuota: true
            }),
            beneficiary
        )
    {
        _setDefaultRoyalty(royaltyReceiver, 1000);
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    /**
    @dev Mint tokens purchased via the Seller.
     */
    function _handlePurchase(
        address to,
        uint256 n,
        bool
    ) internal override {
        _safeMint(to, n);
    }

    /**
    @dev Record of already-used signatures.
     */
    mapping(bytes32 => bool) public usedMessages;

    /**
    @notice Mint tokens.
     */
    function mintPublic(
        address to,
        bytes32 nonce,
        bytes calldata sig
    ) external payable {
        signers.requireValidSignature(
            signaturePayload(to, nonce),
            sig,
            usedMessages
        );
        _purchase(to, 1);
    }

    function alreadyMinted(address to, bytes32 nonce)
        external
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        return
            usedMessages[
                SignatureChecker.generateMessage(signaturePayload(to, nonce))
            ];
    }

    /**
    @dev Constructs the buffer that is hashed for validation with a minting
    signature.
     */
    function signaturePayload(address to, bytes32 nonce)
        internal
        pure
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        return abi.encodePacked(to, nonce);
    }


    /**
    @dev Required override to select the correct baseTokenURI.
     */
    function _baseURI()
        internal
        view
        override(BaseTokenURI, ERC721A)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return BaseTokenURI._baseURI();
    }

    /**
    @notice If set, contract to which tokenURI() calls are proxied.
     */
    ITokenURIGenerator public renderingContract;

    /**
    @notice Sets the optional tokenURI override contract.
     */
    function setRenderingContract(ITokenURIGenerator _contract)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        renderingContract = _contract;
    }

    /**
    @notice If renderingContract is set then returns its tokenURI(tokenId)
    return value, otherwise returns the standard baseTokenURI + tokenId.
     */
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        if (address(renderingContract) != address(0)) {
            return renderingContract.tokenURI(tokenId);
        }
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    /**
    @notice Sets the contract-wide royalty info.
     */
    function setRoyaltyInfo(address receiver, uint96 feeBasisPoints)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        _setDefaultRoyalty(receiver, feeBasisPoints);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721ACommon, ERC2981, AccessControlEnumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

It compiles ok, but when I tried to create a test for minting, I must generate a valid signature...

This is the test

```
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe("TestBirds", function () {
    it ("Should return correct name, URI, owner and beneficiary", async function () {

        const [owner, addr1] = await hre.ethers.getSigners()
               
        provider = ethers.provider

        const TestBirdsContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TestBirds")
        const testBirdsContractDeployed = await TestBirdsContract.deploy(
            "TestBirds",
            "APFP",
            "https://test.url/",
            owner.address,
            owner.address)

        console.log(await provider.getBalance(owner.address));
        await testBirdsContractDeployed.deployed()

        const nonce = await ethers.provider.getTransactionCount(owner.address, "latest")
        await testBirdsContractDeployed.mintPublic(owner.address, nonce, signature???)
       
        expect(await testBirdsContractDeployed.name()).to.equal("TestBirds")
        expect(await testBirdsContractDeployed.tokenURI(0), "https://test.url/0")
        expect(await testBirdsContractDeployed.ownerOf(0)).to.equal(owner.address)
    })
})
```

How should I sing this in order to work? I can not test the contract without the sign. If I remove the signature param from the contract it works, but that is not what I want.

Thanks

Comment: beggining at line 87, where is `signers` coming from?
I sent your contract to a remix workspace to try it out and it complains on that specific `mintPublic()` function

Comment: @PedroHenriqueBufulin it is defined on SignerManager.sol. Like in this contract for example https://etherscan.io/address/0xe0176ba60efddb29cac5b15338c9962daee9de0c#code .

Comment: That a look at the `SignerManager.sol` source code. Where is `signers.requireValidSignature()` coming from? It's not from SignerManager.
`signers` is simply an address set. I think I understand what you want to do in the `MintPublic()` method, but I think it is not the way you are trying to.

What exactly do you want to accomplish with this method? Do you want to allow only specific addresses to be able to mint?

Comment: `signers` is also an internal variable of the `SignerManager.sol` so it can't be accessed from your contract.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueBufulin It is possible as you see here https://etherscan.io/address/0xe0176ba60efddb29cac5b15338c9962daee9de0c#code  ... my problem is that I do not know how to generate a signature from my test

Comment: I took a better look and I think I understand it better now. 
Let me try to give you an example on how to make a valid ECDSA signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only missing was to add a signer. This seems to work for your test contract...

```js
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

describe("Test signature", function () {
  it("deploy tester contract, and send signed message", async function () {
    const TestSignature = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestSignature",owner);
    const testSignature = await TestSignature.deploy();
    await testSignature.deployed();

    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

     // missing line
    testSignature.addSigner(owner.address);

    const params = ethers.utils.solidityPack(
      ["address", "uint256", "bytes32"],
      [owner.address, "10", ethers.utils.keccak256("0x66")]
    );

    const signed = await owner.signMessage(params);
    console.log("owner address", owner.address);

    await testSignature.mint(
      owner.address,
      "10",
      ethers.utils.keccak256("0x66"),
      signed
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted the following, but without much success yet:

```js
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

describe("Test signature", function () {
  it("deploy tester contract, and send signed message", async function () {
    const TestSignature = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestSignature");
    const testSignature = await TestSignature.deploy();
    await testSignature.deployed();

    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const params = ethers.utils.solidityPack(
      ["address", "uint256", "bytes32"],
      [owner.address, "10", ethers.utils.keccak256("0x66")]
    );

    const signed = await owner.signMessage(params);
    console.log("owner address", owner.address);

    await testSignature.mint(
      owner.address,
      "10",
      ethers.utils.keccak256("0x66"),
      signed
    );
  });
});
```

That is a test against the following contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "./SignatureChecker.sol";

contract TestSignature {
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;
    using SignatureChecker for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;

    EnumerableSet.AddressSet internal signers;

    constructor() {
        signers.add(msg.sender);
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => bool) public usedMessages;

    function mint(
        address to,
        uint256 price,
        bytes32 nonce,
        bytes calldata sig
    ) external payable {
        signers.requireValidSignature(
            signaturePayload(to, price, nonce),
            sig,
            usedMessages
        );
    }

    /**
    @dev Constructs the buffer that is hashed for validation with a minting signature.
     */
    function signaturePayload(
        address to,
        uint256 price,
        bytes32 nonce
    ) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodePacked(to, price, nonce);
    }

    function generateMessage(bytes memory data) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return SignatureChecker.generateMessage(data);
    }
}
```

From what I understood, the signed message should match the message, and the `ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(data)`
appends the `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n` to the beggining of the message. After it matches, it can recover the signer address, but it doesn't seem to work quite right yet.

Comment: payload matches what there is on tests as params matches with what the contract generates (signaturePayload(to, price, nonce)) but it seem there is a problem with the signature, not sure why

Comment: Maybe the equivalent of: "const signature = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(
    'Hello world',
    // below is private key to the address `0x0647EcF0D64F65AdA7991A44cF5E7361fd131643`
    '02ed07b6d5f2e29907962d2bfde8f46f03c46e79d5f2ded0b1e0c27fa82f1384'
);" works, but I am not sure how to do that on hardhat

Comment: Interesting. The equivalent in ethers would be: `const signedHello = await owner.signMessage("Hello world");`. 

You can try using web3js but I think the problem is not there. I believe those methods are equivalent and return the same output.

Comment: I have tried also with `PlayForeverPassContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("PlayForeverPass", owner)`, setting the owner as the deployer of the contract, which makes sense....right? But still I have the same error

Comment: There is something we are missing. Let's try the plain ECDSA.recover() function in the contract, if we can make it work with offchain signatures